# Overriding class method in ruby not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop, cancan

I have a base controller to DRY up a lot of my bog standard crud controllers, the idea being that I only override each method if I need to do something non standard.

```
class MyBaseController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  # Common crud actions

end
```

Now in one of my child controllers I have a custom action (export_csv)

```
class ReportsController < MyBaseController 

  load_and_authorize_resource :except => :export_csv

  def export_csv
    # custom auth and other stuff
  end

end
```

Now I can no longer hit my export_csv action, instead I get an access denied exception. If I don't inherit from my base controller all is good.

I thought I might be able to work around it as follows:

```
class MyBaseController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource :except => auth_exceptions

  def self.auth_exceptions
    []
  end

  # Common crud actions

end
```

And then override self.auth_exceptions in my child classes as necessary.

However this triggers the error "undefined local variable or method `auth_exceptions' for MyBaseController:Class"

Does anyone have any suggestions to selectively override load and authorize resource in my child controllers?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea altogether: some controllers could not represent any resource and you'll have to patch everything.

Comment: In those cases I can just inherit straight from ApplicationController?

Comment: yes, depends on what you expect. Hope you don't over DRY things, it leads to expensive futur changes

Comment: I'm making these changes off the back of feedback from codeclimate.com, a lot of my crud actions haven't changed much from the generated scaffold so it has highlighted a lot of my controllers as having duplicated code...

Comment: CodeClimate gives precious hints, that's really sure. But you only can apprehend your app as a whole, do what you consider best, I just want you to have all cards in hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in your derived class:

```
skip_load_and_authorize_resource :only => :export_csv
```

Doc's here: [skip_load_and_authorize_resource](http://rubydoc.info/gems/cancan/CanCan/ControllerAdditions/ClassMethods%3askip_load_and_authorize_resource).